# Trying to integrate form input to kinetic.js stage

Tags: kineticjs

I have a stage/canvas built with kinetic and for the moment, I am achieving what I need... But, I need to make it dynamic in a sense whereby, users can fill a form on the same page and on submit, the input is sent to a javascript and displayed on the canvas stage.. so far, i have had no luck using javascript's getElementById on the same script that handles the canvas display... Can someone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response. I have fixed the issue using php. Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now sure how much I can help but here you go.. My solution is implemented using PHP/AJAX/jQuery/Kinetic.... though not done with the complete solution yet ; what i'm trying to achieve is that, a user fills a form and on submit, PHP passes the values to a kinetic canvas.. below is what I use to build a text layer..mind you, this is a javascript snippet with a little php to output the text string..

```
    var companyMessage = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: 5,
        y: 35,
        fill: 'transparent',
        text: '<?php echo $coy_messg ?>', // php code wrapped between php tags
        fontSize: 14,
        fontFamily: 'Georgia',
    textFill: '#555',
        padding: 4,
        align: 'center',
        fontStyle: 'normal',
        cornerRadius: 0,
        draggable: true,
      });
// add cursor styling
      companyMessage.on('mouseover', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'move';
      });
      companyMessage.on('mouseout', function() {
         document.body.style.cursor = 'default'; 
      });
```

does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anyone else has this problem (like me ;p), here is a fiddle, using a javascript variable and the kinetic JS node.setText property to update the canvas:

http://jsfiddle.net/skye/zBUQs/1/

```
//Make a variable to hold the updatable canvas text//
var newName = 'some text to look at';

//Create canvas text with variable inside it
var complexText = new Kinetic.Text({
            x: 30,
            y: 50,
            text: newName,
            fontSize: 18,
            fontFamily: 'Calibri',
            fill: '#555',
            width: 380

 });

//Add text to layer
layer.add(complexText);
//Add layer to stage
stage.add(layer);

//On button click
$('#updateBtn').click(function (e) {

       //change the value of newname to the input value
       newName = $('#name').val();
        //insert the new value into the canvas text
       complexText.setText(newName);
        //redraw the layer
       layer.draw();

    });
```